# Unable to install Ubuntu (20.04) on Intel NUC

Tags: 20.04

I have the Intel NUC7i3BNK. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Live works perfectly. The Lenovo monitor is detected, and the resolution is correct 2560x1440 (16:9).
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installation works witjout any problems. Unfortunately, the boot attempt now results in completely black screen and totally unresponsive system.
Any suggestions for solving this issue? Thanks!